# Apostrophe issue with FFmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, apostrophe, ffmpeg-php

I'm working on a company's project which is vue.js.
There are also code parts in php.
It uses FFmpeg to create a video from multiple videos.
On each video, there is a text type subtitle.
Each text is retrieved from a .txt file
But I have a problem with apostrophes.

If in the subtitle is stored like this ( I'm here ) in the txt file, on the video there will be written ( Im ).
The apostrophe is removed and the rest of the text too ( here ) will not be displayed.

I'm new to php and ffmpeg, I've been on this problem for almost 3 weeks.

I share the php code with you.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

array_shift($argv); // remove script name in $argv[0]

$parameters = array_reduce($argv, function ($carry, $arg) {
    $tokens = explode('=', $arg);
    $carry[$tokens[0]] = $tokens[1];
    return $carry;
}, []);

$projectPath = $parameters['projectPath'];
$musicPath = $parameters['musicPath'];

$fontPath = getcwd() . "/public/fonts/cobol/Cobol-Bold.ttf";
$logoPath = getcwd() . "/public/images/saintex.jpg";
$carnetLogoPath = getcwd() . "/public/images/CarnetTitre.jpg";

// Adding descriptions for each clip and fade in and fade out filters
$clipsToDescribe =  glob("$projectPath/*.webm");
$clipFrameRate = (int) shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate $clipsToDescribe[0]");
$clipFrameRate = $clipFrameRate > 60 ? 30 : $clipFrameRate;

foreach ($clipsToDescribe as $key => $clipToDescribe) {
    $clipIndex = $key + 1;
    $clipFrames = (int) shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 $clipToDescribe");
    $clipDuration = (float) ($clipFrames / $clipFrameRate) - 0.5;
    file_put_contents("$projectPath/clip{$clipIndex}_desc.txt", addslashes($parameters["clip{$clipIndex}_desc"]));
    shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -i $clipToDescribe -vf 'drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath: textfile=clip{$clipIndex}_desc.txt: fontcolor=white: fontsize=46: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-50): fix_bounds=true, fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.3,fade=t=out:st=$clipDuration:d=0.3' -b:v 3000K -b:a 192K clip{$clipIndex}.webm");
}
array_map('unlink', glob("$projectPath/*desc.txt"));

shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -t 2 -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720 -r 30 blank.webm");
shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -i blank.webm -i $carnetLogoPath -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v] overlay=(main_w/2)-(overlay_w/2):(main_h/2)-(overlay_h/2)' -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy logo.webm");



$workshop = $parameters["workshop_type"];
$title = $parameters["title"];
shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:duration=3:rate=30:color=black -vf 'drawtext=text=$workshop:fontfile=$fontPath:fontcolor=white:fontsize=46:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2, drawtext=text=$title:fontfile=$fontPath:fontcolor=white:fontsize=46:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=((h-text_h)/2)+lh+5' opening.webm");
unlink("$projectPath/blank.webm");

$videosFile = "file 'logo.webm'\n";
$videosFile .= "file 'opening.webm'\n";{
    file_put_contents("$projectPath/project_desc.txt", $parameters["project_desc"]);
    shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:duration=3:rate=30:color=black -vf 'drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath:fontsize=46:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:textfile=project_desc.txt' project_desc.webm");
    unlink("$projectPath/project_desc.txt");
    $videosFile .= "file 'project_desc.webm'\n";
} 
if(array_key_exists("participants", $parameters)) {
    file_put_contents("$projectPath/participants.txt", "Participants :\n" . $parameters["participants"]);
    shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:duration=2:rate=30:color=black -vf 'drawtext=fontfile=$fontPath:fontsize=46:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:textfile=participants.txt' participants.webm");
    unlink("$projectPath/participants.txt");
}

$videos =  glob("$projectPath/clip*.webm");
foreach($videos as $video) {
    if($video != "originalVideos") {
        $videosFile .= "file ". "'{$video}'\n";
    }
} 
if(array_key_exists("participants", $parameters)) {
    $videosFile .= "file '$projectPath/participants.webm'";
}
array_map('unlink', glob("$projectPath/*webm.txt"));
file_put_contents("$projectPath/videosFile.txt", $videosFile);
if($musicPath == "/_musics/") {
    echo(shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i videosFile.txt -b:v 10000K -crf 20 -b:a 192K output.webm"));
} else {
    echo(shell_exec("cd $projectPath && ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i videosFile.txt -b:v 10000K -crf 20 -b:a 192K assembled.webm && ffmpeg -i assembled.webm -i ../..$musicPath -filter_complex ' [1:0] apad ' -shortest -y -b:v 3000K -b:a 192K output.webm"));
}
```

I tried many things but each time there were errors.
I think I didn't implement the code properly.

I share you the error

```
        [09:21:02] RECEIVED EVENT: videoRequest
{ Error: Command failed: php ./public/src/generate.php projectPath='/home/rohan/Documents/dodoc2/_projects/its-a-test' musicPath='/_musics/classic.mp3' clip1_name='' clip2_name='' clip3_name='' clip4_name='' clip5_name='' clip1_desc='It's a first test' clip2_desc='It's a second test' clip3_desc='It's a third test' clip4_desc='It's a fourth' clip5_desc='It's a last test' project_desc='' workshop_type='Atelier Robotique' title='It's a test' participants='Molinillo Rohan
'
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 9
ffmpeg version 5.1.1-1ubuntu2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu2.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --disable-sndio --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-librsvg --enable-libmfx --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libplacebo --enable-shared
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/home/rohan/Documents/dodoc2/_projects/its-a-test/video-20230404-091933-682.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : QTmuxingAppLibWebM-0.0.1
  Duration: N/A, start: -0.001000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 1k tbr, 1k tbn (default)
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp8 (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x55952c183000] v1.12.0
Output #0, webm, to 'clip1.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9, yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 3000 kb/s, 1k fps, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libopus
frame=  229 fps= 11 q=12.0 Lsize=    2786kB time=00:00:07.52 bitrate=3034.7kbits/s speed=0.377x    
video:2601kB audio:181kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.175036%
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "clip2_desc" in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 29
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: addslashes(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, null given in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php(29): addslashes()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/rohan/carnet-numerique/public/src/generate.php on line 29

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:554:12)
  killed: false,
  code: 255,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'php ./public/src/generate.php projectPath=\'/home/rohan/Documents/dodoc2/_projects/its-a-test\' musicPath=\'/_musics/classic.mp3\' clip1_name=\'\' clip2_name=\'\' clip3_name=\'\' clip4_name=\'\' clip5_name=\'\' clip1_desc=\'It\'s a first test\' clip2_desc=\'It\'s a second test\' clip3_desc=\'It\'s a third test\' clip4_desc=\'It\'s a fourth\' clip5_desc=\'It\'s a last test\' project_desc=\'\' workshop_type=\'Atelier Robotique\' title=\'It\'s a test\' participants=\'Molinillo Rohan\n\'' }
```

Comment: "but each time there were errors"... Please edit your question and include these errors

Comment: Ok; line 9. So, can you share a filename that causes problems?

Comment: i can't, because when i start a new project, the script create a new folder with the name of the project to store all txt files and videos files.

Comment: You must properly escape arguments. Every language has that option... For PHP, it's [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)